# Getting Empty Buffer after Tx submission : Fabric 2.1 with fabric-network client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am using fabric 2.1, with new client library fabric-network. I have configured network, created channel, installed chaincode, etc. I could invoke transactions through CLI.

Fabric Version: 2.1
fabric-network:2.1

I have defined Event Handler Strategy as below
1) strategy: DefaultEventHandlerStrategies.MSPID_SCOPE_ANYFORTX

2) strategy: createTransactionEventHandler

```
await gateway.connect(ccp, {
            wallet, identity: username, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true }, transaction: {
                strategy: DefaultEventHandlerStrategies.MSPID_SCOPE_ANYFORTX
            }
        });
```

When I submit the transaction, getting an empty buffer in both cases instead of transaction id(Not sure if we get tx id).

**The invoked transaction is getting added to the blockchain. I confirmed it from CouchDB and querying the asset.**

```
> let result = await contract.submitTransaction(fcn, args[0], args[1],args[2], args[3], args[4]);
```

I tried with a custom event handler, but this function is not getting triggered.  strategy: createTransactionEventHandler

> ```
> const createTransactionEventHandler = (transactionId, network) => {
>     const mspId = network.getGateway().getIdentity().mspId;
>     const myOrgPeers = network.getChannel().getEndorsers(mspId);
>     console.log(`tx id : ${transactionId}`)
>
>     return new MyTransactionEventHandler(transactionId, network, myOrgPeers);
> }
> ```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the chaincode, I had a similar issue where I was receiving an empty Buffer. If you are using fabcar, I assume you are calling this function:

```
async createCar(ctx, carNumber, make, model, color, owner) {
    console.info('============= START : Create Car ===========');

    const car = {
        color,
        docType: 'car',
        make,
        model,
        owner,
    };

    await ctx.stub.putState(carNumber, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));
    console.info('============= END : Create Car ===========');
    return car; // if you don't return anything you get an empty response
}
```

So check if your chaincode is supposed to return anything in the first place.